# GC.GetGeneration() returns always 0 for int variable even after calling GC.Collect() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Below is code snippet in which I am getting generation of variable `int j` before and after calling garbage collector.

```
int j = 30;
WriteLine(GC.GetGeneration(j) );
GC.Collect();
WriteLine(GC.GetGeneration(j));
```

The output should be

```
0
1
```

as `int j` is surviving garbage collection But I am getting

```
0
0
```

I don't understand why this is happening because `int` is also an object in C#.
PS: I have tried running project in debug as well as in release mode.

Comment: `j` is a value type, not a reference type and unless a value type is heap allocated it lives on the stack and isnt rooted in the GC at all. What are you trying to prove here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How garbage collection decides generation for variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521919/how-garbage-collection-decides-generation-for-variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. an `int` is a value type and is not tracked by the garbage collector. Since `GetGeneration` takes an `object`, the int will be [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). I.e. a new object will be created. That new object will always be allocated in gen 0. The next time you call `GetGeneration` the same thing will occur.

So your results are as expected.